# C++ dynamic memory allocation (char[] and int[])

Tags: c++, char, int, operator-overloading, new-operator

`str` is a pointer, why not use `str` for input and output? Not `*str`.
 `p` is a pointer, why use `*p` for input and output? Not `p`.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
    char* str = new char[20];
    cin>>str;
    cout<<str<<endl;
    delete []str;

    int* p = new int[3];
    cin>>*p;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    delete []p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wat? What are you asking?  Also there are two bugs, both `delete  x;` should be `delete[]  x;` or memory is in undefined state

Comment: I want to know the difference between `str` and `*str`.

Comment: pointer and object it is point at , respectively. what is the confusion here.?

Comment: You always have to dereference the point like `*p` with stream objects *except* for `char *` and `const char*`. The stream classes have special functions specifically designed to handle those, for the purpose of reading and writing null terminated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator overloads `<<` and `>>` have special overloads for `const char*` and `char*` respectively, because those are null-terminated C-style strings. They are
treated diifferently than other pointers/other arrays.

Here's a little comparison of the semantics used:

```
cin >> str;
```

means "read a null terminated string into an array, where `str` is the pointer to the first element".

```
cout << str;
```

means "Print a null terminated string, where `str` is the pointer to the first element".

---

However there are such semantics for other pointer types like `int*`.

```
cin >> p;
```

wont work, there is no such thing as "reading an array of ints", or "reading a pointer", while

```
cin >> *p;
```

works and means "read a single integer and store it in the value of `p`", that is, the first element in the array get's modified.

```
cout << p;
```

means "print the value of the pointer", again, because there are no special semantics for `int*` like "Print array of ints". On the other hand

```
cout << *p;
```

meanse "Print one integer, that is the value of `p`", that is, the first element in the array get's printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str = new char[20];
cin>>str;
```

You are passing the pointer to a series of char to `cin` because `cin` is expected to read multiple chars at the location pointed to by the pointer.

```
int* p = new int[3];
cin>>*p;
```

You are passing a single int, by reference, to `cin`, because `cin` is expected to read a single int. There is no read functionality that will read a sequence of ints, because a sequence of int is not an usual thing. However, a sequence of char is a c-string and a typical thing. That's why `cin` has an overload that reads to a char pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to rewrite this code snippet

```
int* p = new int[3];
cin>>*p;
cout<<*p<<endl;
delete []p;
```

like

```
int* p = new int;
cin>>*p;
cout<<*p<<endl;
delete p;
```

because there is used only one object of the allocated array of three objects of the type int.

In the first case you are dealing with a character array that accepts or stores a string. For character arrays for example the operator >> is declared like

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>&,
charT*);
```

That is the operator needs to get access not only to the first character of the array but also to subsequent characters of the array using the pointer arithmetic. The operator does not change the passed pointer. It changes the objects of the type character pointed to by the pointer.

For objects of the type int the operator >> is declared like

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(int& n);
```

It is enough to pass a scalar object by reference to change it using the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Cause a pointer is a variable who's value is an adress, the value of the adress pointed is then accessible by the * operator.
example :

`char *str = new char[20];`

str is a pointer so it has :

_ an adress `&str = adress1`
_ a value   `str = adress2` (it's adress because it's a pointer)

And at this adress2 are 20 character on continuous adress, so first character would be in adress adress2, then next one adress2+1, then adress2+2 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there was  a grammar mishap in bullet 1.

1. `str` is a pointer to a char but in this case it point to first one in an array of such. `*str` is a reference to single char (byte). pointers can be used to pass string by passing address of array's beginning. We are guaranteed to be able to increment that pointer and dereference it in order to access following characters

E.g. this is how `strlen` may work:

```
  size_t strlen(char *p)
  {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (*p++ != 0) len ++;
    return len;
  }
```

2. `p` is value of pointer to int, there is no meaning in writing to it. `*p` is reference to first element of array, of type `int`.